# Escaping * char in cshell alias

Tags: shell, escaping

Escaping * char in  cshell alias

i want to write a C Shell Alias which can find files starting with a pattern

ie equivalent of 
find . -name  "pattern*"

myfind pattern 
should do above cmd where myfind is the alias name.  How do i escape the * in csh alias ?

alias myfind 'find . -name !**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to escape. This works as -

```
alias myfind "find . -name 'pattern*'"
```

Comment: Single quotes are more or less equivalent to escaping.

Comment: Agreed. I should have said "no need to escape '*'s specifically"

Answer (score 0):

```
# the above post doesn't take into account \* arguments (including spaces in arguments)


# The original alias is useful for when you have time to type quotes or your
# arguments need to be regular expressions
alias ff 'find . -iname \!* -follow -print'

# alias fff (below) is of limited utility, because your arguments can't be regular
# expressions or enclosed in quotes.  It is useful for quick and dirty situations
# when you want to cut and paste things with spaces in them without using quotes.
# the combination of double quotes and single quotes here is very important.
# rules of thumb for "I hate typing quotes" style aliases:
#   enclose alias arguments \* in this construct:    '"\*"'
#   conversely, enclose wildcards in this construct: "'*'"
alias fff "find . -iname '*'"'"\!*"'"'*' -follow -print"
```

**examples at prompt**

```
/Projects/mbox/Installers/Mbox Studio Installer>alias ff
find . -iname !* -follow -print
/Projects/mbox/Installers/Mbox Studio Installer>ff "Mbox *.app"
./ROOT/Applications/Mbox Studio/Mbox Remote.app
./ROOT/Applications/Mbox Studio/Mbox Studio.app
./ROOT/Applications/Mbox Utilities/Mbox Controller.app
/Projects/mbox/Console>alias fff
find . -iname '*'"!*"'*' -follow -print
/Projects/mbox/Installers/Mbox Studio Installer>fff Mbox Studio
./NightlyBuild/DiskImages/Mbox Studio 3.6D3435.dmg
./NightlyBuild/DiskImages/Mbox Studio 3.6D3438.dmg
./ROOT/Applications/Mbox Studio
./ROOT/Applications/Mbox Studio/Mbox Studio.app
```